# How can I display elements of my list with specific delay using C#?

Tags: c#, list

I have a list called List-3 which consists of bitmap images as elements. My question is how I can display each of the elements (images) to my picturebox one-by-one with 10 millisecond delay.

Comment: Please expand on "does not work"

Comment: i mean it does not show a sequence of image. in fact it doesn't show anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to go too deep into the implementation details, but your `Timer.Tick` event has 3 delegates subscribed to it, one for each `Bitmap`, and they'll all run one after another, every 10 milliseconds

What you probably want to do is to switch to a new `Bitmap` ever 10 milliseconds.  In order to do that, you only need 1 timer event, which goes to the next image.

```
timer.Tick += delegate
{
    ...
    pictureBox3.Image = list(counter);
    counter = (counter+1)%3;
    ...
};// end of timer
```

Comment: Note, you will want to dispose of the old image you are overwriting too or you may run in to memory issues. `var temp = pictureBox3.Image; pictureBox3.Image = list(counter); temp.Dispose();`

Comment: could you pleas give more clear explanation, do i need to remove timer.Start(); from the bottom of my code?

Comment: @user3384676  no, that's what the `...` is for

Comment: @user3384676  the reason I posted the code sample that I did was just to illustrate that you only need to add 1 delegate to `timer.Tick`, and not 3 delegates.  It wasn't intended to dive into syntax issues or other implementation details.